# UIPageViewController with only one content view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app with webView and some JS-tricks to present text. Paging is implemented in JS and I just pass events from gestures to JS functions.
But what I miss is animation. Know user just see another portion of text when he turns the page with swipe.
So I decided to use UIPageViewController. I need a one controller to be shown and it will change it state during animation of turning. So the same one will be returned every time in

```
-(UIViewController*) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

and

```
- (UIViewController*) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Now I have an error doing this.

Finally, the question - can only one controller be used for proper animation in pageViewController?

Comment: Did you ever work this out?  I have an identical scenario that I'm trying to implement right now.  Thanks!

Comment: Nope, last try was with iOS 5.1 and it wasn't possible to use 1 view controller for paging. Several ones needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIView`'s `transitionWithView:` method to animate content changes and add a curl animation just like this:

```
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    animations:^{
                        // change your content here
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        // optional completion block
                    }];
```

Comment: Yes, nice solution but not the perfect one - such animation has only up and down directions but not left and right.

Comment: The only possible solution, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you actually want to use a simple `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled`. Maybe you confused `UIPageViewController` with `UIPageControl`?

Comment: Nope. I need book-like animation and my content is already screen-sized. So no scroll needed.