# Android WebView page transition effects on content changes (page curl)

Tags: android, android-webview, android-transitions, page-curl

I want to implement native page transition curl effect on a `WebView` after the *content changed* (that means, the page is not being reloaded!).

One common solution is using Animations before loading a new page, e.g. with a custom `WebViewClient`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319579/1684030

However, this only works if there's actually *a new page being loaded*. In my case I have a `WebView` displaying a javascript app which just switches the contents of a `div` ("single page application"). Animating those content changes with javascript leads to a laggy solution, so I wanted to try to implement it natively.

For iOS, this seems to be possible ([UIPageViewController with only one content view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015370/uipageviewcontroller-with-only-one-content-view-controller) - I know, Android OS and iOS are not quite comparable, I just wanted to mention it) and I was asking myself if there is some similar solution for Android as well.

Comment: Have to tried using JavaScript Bridge? It's been long time though! Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javaScript bridge to call your Java method which performs the curl transition effect on webView.

```
mWebView.addJavaScriptInterface(new JsObject, "injectedObject");
```

Refer: [Android developers - JS Interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))

There are some implemented [JS bridge in Github](https://github.com/lzyzsd/JsBridge).